# MySQL Query Date Great than specific date

Tags: mysql, date

I am typing to run a query against a table with the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE stock_current.Manufacturer = 5 AND
stock_current.date_despatched > 2013-10-01 AND
stock_current.StockStatus = 5
```

but it is returning all dates.

Comment: sorry should have added the date_despatched is a date field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the date

```
AND stock_current.date_despatched > '2013-10-01'
```

Only numbers don't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work

```
WHERE stock_current.Manufacturer = 5 AND
DATE(stock_current.date_despatched) > '2013-10-01' AND
stock_current.StockStatus = 5
```

Comment: OP mentioned that `date_despatched` is a date field already, Using `DATE()` removes the ability of using indexes which makes the query slow.

Comment: Then just removing the DATE will be fine

Comment: Let me know if you have further problems